# Visual representation of a Ranking over time (image provided)

Tags: python, image, wolfram-mathematica, ranking

The graph below shows a ranking of countries at 10 different points. The cool thing with this graph is that it allows you to track changes in the ranking over time.  I want to create create something similar, but I have no idea how it was created...

My guess is that it was created using some design tool like adobe indesign, but my hope is that there might be some other tools for obtaining such a graphic (maybe even a way to do it within Mathematica or Python?)?

Any ideas and/or suggestions on where to look would be much appreciated.

PS: In case I did not post this in the most appropriate of stackExchange's many forums--my apology.

[image: Source: Hidalgo and Hausmann (2010)]

Comment: You might get (better) answers at http://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: cross posted here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66608/193

Comment: see answer from @belisarius here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/visual-representation-of-a-ranking-over-time-image-provided/66608#66608

Answer (score 0):

it is called a bump chart, you can learn how to make it with python in this article
[How to make a bump chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095438/how-to-make-a-bump-chart)

Comment: the answer you are arguing can be supplemented with more information please add more information by editing and also read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)